# Unity setting the transform.localEulerAngles problems

Tags: rotation, unityscript, quaternions

I want to give a Vetor3 value to a transform's rotation, and I use

`transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(170,0,0);`

then, I run the game,but the rotation of the transform isn't (170,0,0),that's confused.  And I try to some other values, I find that if the value of x <=90, it worked well, and what ever the y or z value is ,they wouldn't get trouble, I searched on google but didn't get any good answer, can you guys help me out ? why I can't set a value >90 to x rotation? And if I have to set value for x rotation , how should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3gS0.jpg)

Comment: Euler angle rotations are easy to conceptualize but difficult to implement. The x,y,z rotations are applied one after the other, in order I don't know. But what I do know is that it is discouraged to set rotations like that. Internally, what ever you do in Euler, gets translated in Quaternion. So you will be much better off using the methods provided  for rotational mathematics. Eulers come with all sorts of inherent problems, and Quaternions are so difficult to understand.

Comment: I tried to translate Euler Angle to Quaternions,but still didn't get the right result.

Comment: I code like this: ‘ transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z)’,but when the x bigger than 90, it will get bad result.Any way, tks your answer! I'll try to get it done